# Pipe output from several commands into 1 line

Tags: raspbian, script

I am wondering how to pipe the outputs from several commands (4 commands to be precise) into one single line in a text-file. For no I have the following code that pipes the output into 4 different lines

```
($skriptdate && $skripttime; && eval $temp; && eval $humid;) >> /home/pi/test12345.txt
```

What do I need to do to make it write on one single line?

Comment: Is there any way someone could move this question to the right topic, as it appears to be Off-Topic here?

Answer (score 2):

@goldilocks approach is good!

---

i would advise doing that with

```
echo -n $( your commands ) >> whatever.txt
```

or in pipe mode

```
your commands | xargs echo -n >> whatever.txt
```

prinft is killing the whitespaces \s .. i really dont know why.. maybe anybody got an explanation for this behavior?

```
your commands | xargs printf %s >> whatever.txt
printf %s $( your commands ) >> whatever.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe through `tr`:

```
(your commands) | tr '\n' ' ' >> whatever.txt
```

This actually replaces the newline (`\n`) with a space.  If you just want to remove the newline, use `tr -d '\n'` instead.

See `man tr` for details.